# Select all backslashes between two chars

Tags: regex, powershell

I am working on a powershell script and I've got several text files where I need to replace backslashes in lines which matches this pattern: `.. >\\%name% ..  < ..` (`..` could be anything)

Example string from one of the files where the backslashes **should** match:

```
<Tag>\\%name%\TST$\Program\1.0\000\Program.msi</Tag>
```

Example string from one of the files where the backslashes **should not** match:

```
<Tag>/i /L*V "%TST%\filename.log" /quiet /norestart</Tag>
```

So far I've managed to select every char between `>\\%name%` and `<` with this expression ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Qv5i5t/4)): 
`(?<=>\\\\%name%)(.*)(?=<)` 
but I failed to select only the backslashes.

Is there a solution which I could not yet find?

Comment: I'm not 100% but this may not be possible in regex. Your problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200467/how-to-make-a-group-for-each-word-in-a-sentence) question. I don't see how you can capture every backslash using groups multiple times, without capturing the text between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend selecting the relevant tags with an [XPath expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) and then do the replacement on the text body of the selected nodes.

```
$xml.SelectNodes('//Tag[substring(., 1, 8) = "\\%name%"]' | ForEach-Object {
    $_.'#text' = $_.'#text' -replace '\\', '\\'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So here's my solution:

```
$original_file = $Filepath
$destination_file =  $Filepath + ".new"

Get-Content -Path $original_file | ForEach-Object { 
    $line = $_
    if ($line -match '(?<=>\\\\%name%)(.*)(?=<)'){
       $line = $line -replace '\\','/'
     }
    $line
} | Set-Content -Path $destination_file
Remove-Item $original_file
Rename-Item $destination_file.ToString() $original_file.ToString()
```

So this will [replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403217/how-to-replace-multiple-strings-in-a-file-using-powershell) every \ with an / in the given pattern but not in the way which my question was about.